# SSL certificate for WebAPI

Tags: rest, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, ssl-certificate

We have a simple system with a REST service (WebAPI) that will be hosted on one machine (hosted on IIS on a custom port, port numer 3031) and with a website hosted on another machine that will be talking to the service.

We want both to use SSL, so as I understand we will need to purchase two separate SSL certificates for the production deployment on the Internet.

Does that sound right?

If so, then I don't know how do I request and purchase a certificate for the WebAPI REST service... The service will be hosted on a custom port 3031, should I purchase a normal certificate for the domain name of the machine where the service will be hosted? And then should I basically install the certificate on the IIS on that machine (like it's described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api).

How will I be able to perform a verification of the domain for the purchased certificate if I'm going to use the certificate for a REST service on a custom port? (not for a regular website).

Apologies for my ignorance, I have searched the forum to find an answer to my issue, but I didn't find one, maybe it's because my very limited knowledge about certificates and security.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can bind the same cert/hostname combination to more than one port in iis at once (like 443 and 3031). Does your app and api use the same domain name?

Comment: OK, thank you. I didn't know about that. My REST API will be stored on a separate machine, and the website will be stored on a separate machine (two different APIs and domain names). This is what makes me think I need two separate certificates, does that sound right?

My question is first of all about the certificte for the REST service which will be hosted on IIS. Should I purchase just a normal SSL certificate (just like I would buy a certificate for a website), install it on the IIS, and then configure the IIS-hosted REST service to use it? Will that work?